# Exporting PDF with large PaperSize

Tags: bugs, front-end, export, pdf-format, printing

**Bug present in 10.2 and fixed in 11.2**

 Exporting to eps still produces a crash, but that is another bug.

---

Suppose I create a new Notebook:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell["PDF Test", "Section"],
                     Table[PieChart@Range@5, {7}]}];
```

[image: notebook]

And set a big paper size so that all my charts fit in a single line:

```
SetOptions[nb, PrintingOptions -> {"PaperSize" -> 72 {18, 12}}];
SetOptions[nb, ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Printout"];
```

[image: wide-notebook]

An then I want to export this as PDF. So I issue this command:

```
Export["test6.pdf", nb]
```

The result is that my notebook becomes:

[image: notebook-narrow-again]

and the generated PDF looks like this:

[image]

And the "PaperSize" property is reverted to its default value

```
Options[nb, PrintingOptions]

{PrintingOptions -> {"EmbedExternalFonts" -> True, 
"EmbedStandardPostScriptFonts" -> True, "FacingPages" -> True, 
"FirstPageFace" -> Right, "FirstPageFooter" -> True, 
"FirstPageHeader" -> False, 
"GraphicsPrintingFormat" -> "Automatic", 
"IncludePostScriptResourceDirectives" -> True, 
"IncludeSpecialFonts" -> True, 
"InnerOuterMargins" -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
"Magnification" -> 1., "OpacityRenderingMethod" -> Automatic, 
"PageFooterMargins" -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
"PageHeaderMargins" -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
"PageSize" -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
"PaperOrientation" -> "Portrait", 
"PaperSize" -> {612, 792},
"PostScriptOutputFile" -> Automatic, "PrintCellBrackets" -> False, 
"PrintMultipleHorizontalPages" -> False, 
"PrintRegistrationMarks" -> False, 
"PrintSelectionHighlighting" -> False, 
"PrintingMargins" -> {{54, 54}, {72, 72}}, 
"RasterizationResolution" -> "Automatic", 
"RestPagesFooter" -> True, "RestPagesHeader" -> True, 
"UnixShellPrintingCommand" -> Automatic, 
"UsePostScriptOutputFile" -> False, 
"UseUnixShellPrintingCommand" -> False, 
"VertexColorRenderingMethod" -> Automatic}}
```

If I reset the PaperSize and use the File->Save As.. and used the PDF format, exactly the same happens. If one again I reset the PaperSize and print a PDF file using my new Adobe Acrobat licence, exactly the same happens (but it is slower).

So my question is: How can I get a PDF will all these charts in one row without changing their ImageSize? Is this a bug? Isn't the "Printout" screen environment supposed to match the PDF printout of a notebook? Why is the PaperSize notebook property changed when you Export or print a PDF? Can it be prevented?

I am using Mathematica 10.2 under Windows 7.

Comment: it works if you export to `.tiff`. Perhaps you can find some intermediate format that works and use an external converter.  (`.eps` crashed on me by the way )

Comment: `.eps` crashed on me too. In my real application the notebook is several pages long, so I don't think that `.tiff` is an option. Maybe `.rtf`

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the page size as well as the paper size. I can only test this in V10.1 but it works:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell["PDF Test", "Section"],Table[PieChart@Range@5, {7}]}];
SetOptions[nb, PrintingOptions -> {"PaperOrientation"->"Landscape","PageSize" -> {1296, 864}, 
"PaperSize" -> {1296, 864}}];
SetOptions[nb, ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Printout"];
```

As an FYI if you set the toolbar to display the ruler you will see why setting the page size is required.

Comment: Unfortunately with version 10.2 this does not work: after `Export["test6.pdf", nb]` I obtain a PDF file which looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DuoyS.jpg

Comment: It did not work on my Win7 Mathematica 10.2, and I got a different result than Alexey Popkov: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ9f0.png

Comment: @GustavoDelfino you are using landscape dimensions but a portrait orientation. Try it again using Landscape. You may need to tweek the margins.

Answer (score 3):

If you highlight all the brackets on the right side of what you want, and then do File->Save Selection As you should get this.

```
nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell["PDF Test", 
     "Section"], {Table[PieChart@Range@5, {7}]} // TableForm}];
```

[image]

I transposed the list so it reads left to right and put it in table form to get rid of the brackets.

```
nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell["PDF Test", 
     "Section"], {Table[PieChart@Range@5, {7}]} // TableForm}];
```

[image]

I'm not sure if I had to do this or not, but I made the mathematica window really large and stretched it off my screen so there was plenty of white space to the right of the image before selecting and saving. I think it might matter because my earlier saves still had brackets showing on the right side of the image.

**EDIT:**
Just to be as clear as possible, this is what I meant by "highlight all the  brackets."

[image]

Mathematica 10.0.0 Mac

Comment: (+1) This works with version 10.2 for Windows if I set the Magnification ([Window ► Magnification](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/Magnification_Window.html)) to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

With some modifications.

```
nb = CreateDocument[
   Column[{TextCell["PDF Test", "Section"], 
     GraphicsRow[Table[PieChart@Range@5, {7}], ImageSize -> 700]}]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a trick to reduce the content so that it fits in a letter sized paper. When you open the generated PDF and open the properties windows, you can see that the size is reported as 8.5x11" and not the specified PaperSize.