# How can I export a notebook as a single huge pdf page?

Tags: export, pdf-format, printing

I have a notebook that I would like to export as a pdf file. I currently want to send this to a collaborator, but in general I'd like to keep the technique to future-proof my notebook collection against a day when I might no longer have Mathematica installed.

The notebook in question has a lot of very wide graphics of various sizes, and it occupies most of the 1920px of my screen. The pdf printout is mostly meant to be read on-screen instead of printed, so I do not care about either page width or page breaks. On the other hand, I would like to avoid excessive whitespace on either the right hand side of the page or the bottom. I want the pdf page to be as big as it needs to be, but not bigger - in essence, to be a direct representation of what the Front End actually puts on my screen.

Moreover, I would like to be able to do this programmatically from an external notebook or script that I can then run on a larger collection of notebooks.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible. Your question is related to mine here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95945/exporting-pdf-with-large-papersize     Could exporting to HTML be an alternative?

Comment: @Gustavo That's pretty disappointing. Exporting to HTML is a very-last-ditch option, as it turns all code into images.

Comment: I have been trying that before, but it never worked. I tried to use landscape A3 as the paper format setting to get more horizontal space, but this setting simply doesn't stick, it immediately reverts to letter. One thing that helps is setting the screen environment to "printout"  using the Format menu. Switch on the ruler bar using the Window menu, so that you can see the paper size indicated by a marker. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] Then, change the paper format in the File/Printing options menu to A3 Landscape, and repeat this until you see the paper marker jump to a wider setting. At that point, use File/Save as... PDF to save as a wide pdf.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That's still a lot of manual input, though. It would be nice to automate it at least a bit - save some time on the clicking all over the place, even if there is still a fair bit of human discretion in the paper size you want.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries reverting to letter was a bug confirmed to me by Wolfram about 6-8 months ago from memory. Of course if the bug is fixed it still does not necessarily mean that the above would be possible

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Good to know WRI knows about this.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think I had 10.0.* at the time but have not checked to see if has ben fixed since. The need to do similar no longer existed.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'm using 10.3 and it isn't fixed there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Just for the record (I guess), what OS are you running?

Comment: The OS I'm using is Windows 8.1

Comment: Using Mac OS X 10.11.1 (and probably earlier versions as well) I can just print to pdf by choosing a clearly visible option in the print dialog. It seems to reproduce everything including graphics. However, there are often blank spaces between graphics and the end of the page. Probably those could be eliminated with some sort of PDF processing program, but that is speculation.